# Gstreamer warning: Failed to load plugin libgstcoreelemets.so

Tags: gstreamer, opencv, nvidia-jetson, jetson-xavier, python

Undefined symbol: gst_type_find_helper_for_data_with_extension
[image: Error Screenshot]

Platform: Jetson Xavier NX, gstreamer version:1.0